# Remove blank space from text file

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I have a script to import the names of the virtual machines from hyper-v to a txt file.
The problem is that sometimes the names have blank spaces on the back, and when I try to turn them off or on with the script it does not find those machines because of the blank spaces.

Any way to remove the blank spaces from the file?

```
$vm = Get-VM | select name | Out-File -FilePath $ListVM 
(Get-Content $ListVM | Select-Object -Skip 3) | ? {$_.trim() -ne ""} | Set-Content $ListVM
```

Comment: Why would you export to a text file having the possibility to export to CSV and forget about this kind of issues?

Comment: The server does not have office installed.

Comment: `Export-Csv` and `Import-Csv` are built-in PS cmdlets.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Withstanding Santiago's relevant alternate comment/approach. the cause of your issue may be:

Generally the `Out-*` cmdlets will force objects through PowerShell's for-display formatting system.  You can use `Set-Content` from the start to avoid this, however you cannot simply select the name property doing so will create objects with the single property named "name".  When `Set-Content` sees that it will write hash/object syntax to the file trying to represent the object, like:

```
@{Name=MachineName}
```

To avoid this simply expand the property you want to store in the file:

```
Get-VM | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | 
Set-Content -FilePath $ListVM
```

Or:

```
(Get-VM).Name | Set-Content -FilePath $ListVM
```

Note: you are assigning `$VM` to the output, however that will result in `$VM` being null. I'm not sure what the intent is, but if you want the resulting list stored in the variable add the `-PassThru` parameter like:

```
$vm = (Get-VM).Name | Set-Content -FilePath $ListVM -PassThru
```